# Errors in converting timstamp to hive format in hive

Tags: json, datetime, hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp

I have a JSON data in my hive table which contains a time in following format in milliseconds:

```
...."internal":{"time":["1393404205891"]....
```

I want to get the time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format so that I can query it later to get records only for particular hour duration.
I have tried following ways but still not able to get the time in desired format.

1st TRY:

```
select from_unixtime(cast(get_json_object(log_json,'$.internal.time[0]') as bigint)/1000, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') as time_unix
from slog_table
```

ERROR:

```
No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (double, string)
```

2nd TRY:

```
select from_unixtime (cast ('1393526016039' as int)/1000, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') as time_unix
from slog_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work:

select from_unixtime (cast (1393526016039/1000 as bigint), 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:SS') as time_unix
from slog_table